# tensorflow import error: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

I would like to do Streaming Accuracy and follow the instructions on [Tensorflow Audio recognition official webpage](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/audio_recognition#streaming_accuracy). My environment is Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.5, tensorflow 16.0 in virtualenv.

After I ran this command in a virtualenv environment,

```
bazel run tensorflow/examples/speech_commands:generate_streaming_test_wav
```

some error message came out. Please check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/NearLinHere/44c6dcfbfca0f06dc470cd9a7f4e5200) for more detail.

In brief,

Line 1~7: I would like to make sure that importing tensorflow is ok

Line 9~69: The error message shows that Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

```
INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/generate_streaming_test_wav
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jean_lin/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jean_lin/7ec2afa2cc3b112c8391a9677667186f/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/generate_streaming_test_wav.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/jean_lin/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jean_lin/7ec2afa2cc3b112c8391a9677667186f/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/generate_streaming_test_wav.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/jean_lin/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jean_lin/7ec2afa2cc3b112c8391a9677667186f/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/generate_streaming_test_wav.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/jean_lin/py35_tf16/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/jean_lin/py35_tf16/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/jean_lin/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jean_lin/7ec2afa2cc3b112c8391a9677667186f/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/generate_streaming_test_wav.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jean_lin/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jean_lin/7ec2afa2cc3b112c8391a9677667186f/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/generate_streaming_test_wav.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/generate_streaming_test_wav.py", line 47, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/jean_lin/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jean_lin/7ec2afa2cc3b112c8391a9677667186f/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/generate_streaming_test_wav.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "/home/jean_lin/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jean_lin/7ec2afa2cc3b112c8391a9677667186f/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/generate_streaming_test_wav.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/jean_lin/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jean_lin/7ec2afa2cc3b112c8391a9677667186f/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/generate_streaming_test_wav.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jean_lin/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jean_lin/7ec2afa2cc3b112c8391a9677667186f/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/generate_streaming_test_wav.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/jean_lin/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jean_lin/7ec2afa2cc3b112c8391a9677667186f/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/generate_streaming_test_wav.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/jean_lin/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jean_lin/7ec2afa2cc3b112c8391a9677667186f/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/generate_streaming_test_wav.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/jean_lin/py35_tf16/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/jean_lin/py35_tf16/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/jean_lin/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jean_lin/7ec2afa2cc3b112c8391a9677667186f/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/generate_streaming_test_wav.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Line 72~93: I have no idea why it can't load the native tensorflow. I try to import tensorflow again. And found out that I can't import tensorflow correctly.

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jean_lin/kws/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/platform/self_check.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import build_info
ImportError: cannot import name 'build_info'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jean_lin/kws/tensorflow/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "/home/jean_lin/kws/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/jean_lin/kws/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import self_check
  File "/home/jean_lin/kws/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/platform/self_check.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Could not import tensorflow. Do not import tensorflow "
ImportError: Could not import tensorflow. Do not import tensorflow from its source directory; change directoryto outside the TensorFlow source tree, and relaunch your Python interpreter from there.
```

Any advise would be very appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

About the last error:
ImportError: Could not import tensorflow. Do not import tensorflow from its source directory;

It means that you can't "import tensorflow" in the root of source code path(like:/tensorflow-2.2.0). You just find another path then "import tensorflow".

About the first error , I think I met a similair error, my solution is

1. pip uninstall tensorflow
2. rebuild tensorflow
3. re-pip install tensorflow.